# About DAG dependency execution

Tags: airflow

I have two DAGs in Airflow, namely DAG A and DAGB, which depend on DAG B
I will use TriggerDagRunOperator in DAGA to actively initiate DAG B. I want to achieve the following functions: when DAG A is running, check if DAG B is running. If DAG B has executed within five minutes, do not use TriggerDagRunOperator to trigger DAG B and continue executing other tasks of DAG A. If DAG B has not executed within five minutes, trigger DAG B through TriggerDagRunOperator and wait for DAG B to complete before executing other tasks of DAG A. How should I write DAG A

I checked the document TriggerDagRunOperator and it seems that it can only execute a new DAG and cannot check for already running DAGs. I don't know how to implement the function I want